# Microsoft access report sum function

Tags: ms-access, report

I have a report contain sub report on Microsoft Access database.
I want to sum column in a report and sum another column in a sub report 
 and sum the result from the two columns in a label.

When I try to sum column in a report using expression `-> =sum([outcome])` 
it show `#error` in the sum textbox.

Somebody help me please.

Comment: It has no idea what `outcome` is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the calculation in a Header/Footer

http://www.599cd.com/tips/access/form-footer-total-sum/

---

*Edit*

Could wrap it in an NZ

`=NZ( value, valueIfNull )`

https://599cd.com/glossary/access/nz/

---

Try a DSUM

**Tip**
https://www.599cd.com/tips/access/130809-dsum/

**Glossary**
https://www.599cd.com/glossary/access/dsum/

Comment: What field type is [outcome]

Comment: Do all records contain a value